AWS Cloudfront + Nuxt - Direct link with sub url not working
I use AWS Amplify to deploy my Nuxt static generated web site to S3 then Cloudfront.
My website has sub links like :
/intro
/page
/page/question

etc...
If I am going directly on this Amplify url like, I will be on page "Page Question" : https://mywebsite.amplifyapp.com/page/question
If I am goind through Cloudfront url, it won't work, I got error 403.
If I download the S3 bucket content and start a web server with Python, locally it will works with the same files.
Any idea ?

Did you gave a try to this? https://nuxt.com/deploy/aws-amplify

This is what I implemented, when I say that I use AWS Amplify

I recommend that you try to reach out to the team for further debugging on their Discord. Or might be an AWS thing unrelated to Nuxt. I have absolutely no experience with AWS on that one so sorry for not being able to help further haha.
